# Trash on NTFS for multiple users: Why does Dolphin succeed where Nautilus fails?

Tags: nautilus, ntfs, fstab, trash, dolphin

I am trying to set up the ability for **multiple users** to use the **Trash** on a **NTFS** drive.

The main solution proposed on the forums consists into [enabling a single user to use the Trash](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1499345). That is made by adding the option `uid=1000,gid=1000` into `/etc/fstab`.

Example fstab entry:
`UUID=0A046CF41C7164C6 /media/Data ntfs defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0`

But this only allows the original user, with `id=1000`, to use the Trash. The other users do not have access to it.

A proposed solution for multiple users is to [inherit properties from windows](http://www.tuxera.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=27540). I tried this but I could not make it work.

But I then notice that this may not have anything to do with the way the NTFS drive is mounted:

- Deleting from **Nautilus** displays the message "Impossible to move the file to Trash"
- Deleting from **Dolphin** displays... nothing. And the file is moved to Trash.

But I do not wish to use Dolphin.

So here is my **question**:
Would it be possible to stop messing around with *fstab* and just configure Nautilus correctly? Or does anybody have a simple/working solution to solve this problem?

Note: I am running Ubuntu 11.10 on a 64bits system.

Thanks a lot for your help!

**edit:** And I notice too that Thunar, XFCE File Manager, can also put files to trash without any trouble. So what's up with Nautilus?

Comment: You want users to only send files to Trash? That includes write privilege as far as I know. If the user does not have that privilege they cannot write (or delete) files. If thunar and dolphin allow such behaviour that would actually be a bug of privacy and disregard of user read/write privileges. Can you please post the output of `mount` and `id` commands when you use Dolphin and Thunar?

Comment: @bruno-pereira ^

Answer (score 4):

From what is see in [NTFS-3G](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G) page, under the section "**Allowing Group/User**" `dmask` entry may be the key.

From that page-

You can also tell /etc/fstab (the NTFS-3G driver) other options like those who are allowed to access (read) the partition. For example, for you to allow people in the users group to have access:

```
/dev/<NTFS-part>  /mnt/windows  ntfs-3g   gid=users,umask=0022    0       0
```

By default, the ntfs-3g driver enable write support for root only. To enable user writing, use the dmask parameter to enable user writing:

```
/dev/<NTFS-part>  /mnt/windows  ntfs-3g   gid=users,fmask=113,dmask=002    0       0
```